# Load embed CSS file and make edit to hide element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Can I load an [embedded CSS file](https://shoppy.gg/css/app.css?id=3dc636bb6226024ce3c7) using JavaScript and then edit it to hide the `.embed--powered--logo` class and hide that Powered by Shoppy from the Pop-up window?

The embed code is:

```
<script src='https://shoppy.gg/api/embed.js'/>
<button data-shoppy-product="ID-HERE">Pay</button>
```

I tried with this CSS but not working:

```
<style type='text/css'>
.embed--powered--logo {
clip-path: polygon(0px 0px, 0px 0px, 0px 0px) !important;
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0px 0px, 0px 0px, 0px 0px) !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: If you want to hide it, why not just use `display: none;`?

Comment: This has the distinct odor of an [XY question](http://xyproblem.info). Why are you doing this?

Comment: @dokgu I tried it but not working as this an embed

Comment: Have you tried `.embed--powered--logo{display:none !important}` ? Note the !important attached

Answer (score 0):

I think i know what issue you are having, you want to load an external CSS file and **THEN** change it by your custom file, right?

If that is the case, you could do something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Your document title</title>
    ...

    <script>
      var LinkCss = document.createElement("link");
      LinkCss.href = "path-to-your-css-file.css"; // path to the file you have that css;
      LinkCss.rel = "stylesheet"; // link type, in this case CSS
      document.head.appendChild(LinkCss); // Add to the body

      // Wait for the CSS to load, your custom css file
      LinkCss.onload = function () {
        // When the css is fully loaded

        // Get element with the class name as 'embed--powered--logo'
        var poweredLogo = document.querySelector(".embed--powered--logo");

        // Check if it's not null to prevent errors
        if (poweredLogo) {
          // Hide the element by setting its display to "none"
          poweredLogo.style.display = "none";
        }
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
    <script src="https://shoppy.gg/api/embed.js"></script>
    <button data-shoppy-product="ID-HERE">Pay</button>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: YEAP! You understand exactly what I want to do, I try with the JavaScript code you give but the button no longer works when I click on it nothing happens :(

Comment: It doesn't make sense that it would stop the button from working... strange.

Maybe there is a **pointer-events: none;** somewhere in your CSS files, because what I gave you doesn't use any functions like onclick...

See if there is somewhere in the css file that uses 'pointer-events: none;'.

Comment: Maybe there is an element on front of the button, but it's on opacity 0... The best way to see what is happening, open dev tools [ F12 ], click on the symbol that has a mouse almost inside the box and click on top of the button, if there is something on top, it should select that. If it's not, your code has something like on click function somewhere. Hope it helps